# How to make a grid of similar looking objects?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm about to write some desktop application for mocking something up and I thought it's a good opportunity to try some ne technology. Since app is for Windows and I saw Visual Studio Community edition somewhere I decided to try WPF.

So here's the thing. The base view should look like a simple grid, where each rectangle is an actuall TextBox. I can click and write some text in every each of them.

[image: Base grid]

That was not too bad to achieve. At first I was playing with Grid and ColumnDefinitions and RowDefinitions, which was good for hardcoded ones. After that I gave ItemsControl with ItemTemplate a try and that was pretty much it.

But there's a plot twist now. I want to be able to edit every single TextBox. And by EDIT I mean split it into few smaller TextBoxes. So if I split 2nd one to 2 pieces and 3rd one into 3 pieces it should look like:

[image: Edited grid]

And I have no idea how to tackle this one. Since it's not the same as the other ones I don't think I can use ItemsControl with template anymore (or can I?). I'm quite new with WPF so maybe there's something obvious that I haven't seen just yet. So if there's someone out there who knows WPF quite well and can point me to a right direction or at least tell me "What are you doing? WPF is not good for that kind of apps, use XXX instead".

Comment: Hmm...I see possibly a UniformGrid with 4 columns with 8 children of type EditSplitterControl (which you create) which is a StackPanel of your TextBoxes (which you will put in a UserControl to give some commands like split/close) which will add/subtract from the Items ObservableCollection used to populate the StackPanel (ItemsControl). I'd have to noodle a bit more before mocking this up, but perhaps that is the challenge you are looking for and don't want the sample code. There are probably a few/a dozen other ways to do this as well.

Comment: Thanks guys. I found both of the answers extremally usefull. Too bad I can't accept both answers. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, and there are certainly lots of ways to layout your controls depending on what your app will do, and how you will hook up each control's data to your app/model/whatever.

This answer focuses on layout while taking up all available space and allowing content within each container to replicate. Content flows nicely until the window becomes too small, too narrow, etc. and this is where you need to decide just what your app will allow the user to do. There is plenty of work to do before this code becomes production quality, but is a nice example of some WPF basics to get familiar with the WPF platform.

I added some borders, margins and background colors for testing so you can see what container takes up what space.  Good for testing; possibly remove or change to Transparent in final versions.

[image: WPF Uniform Grid Sample by Kory Gill]

**MainWindow**

XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="WPF" FontSize="36" Margin="20" Foreground="Orange" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="5">
        <Border Background="LightGray" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
            <UniformGrid Columns="4" Name="MainPanel"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private static int _nextId = 0;
    public static int NextId
    {
        get { return _nextId++; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // add non-multiple of 8 to see how layout works
        for (var i=0; i<7; i++)
        {
            MainPanel.Children.Add(new EditPanelControl());
        }
    }
}
```

**EditPanelControl (user control)**

XAML

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Border Background="LightYellow" BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1">
        <!-- Make this a viewbox if you want to show all items but have them shrink -->
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <StackPanel Name="MainPanel" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Code

```
public partial class EditPanelControl : UserControl
{
    public EditPanelControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Loaded += EditPanelControl_Loaded;
    }

    private void EditPanelControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddSuperTextControl();
    }

    private void AddSuperTextControl()
    {
        var stc = new SuperTextControl();
        stc.SplitEvent += Stc_SplitEvent;
        stc.DeleteEvent += Stc_DeleteEvent;
        stc.SuperTextBox.Text = MainWindow.NextId.ToString();
        MainPanel.Children.Add(stc);
    }

    private void Stc_DeleteEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // todo: don't allow delete if only 1 child
        var stc = (SuperTextControl)sender;
        MainPanel.Children.Remove(stc);
    }

    private void Stc_SplitEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var stc = (SuperTextControl)sender; // fyi
        AddSuperTextControl();
    }
}
```

**SuperTextControl (user control)**

XAML

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Border Background="Wheat" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TextBox Name="SuperTextBox" Margin="5"/>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" Margin="0,0,0,5">
                <Button Content="Split" Click="SplitHandler" Margin="5,0" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                <Button Content="Delete" Click="DeleteHandler" Margin="5,0" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Code

```
public partial class SuperTextControl : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler SplitEvent;
    public event EventHandler DeleteEvent;

    public SuperTextControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SplitHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Button)sender; // fyi

        if (SplitEvent != null)
        {
            SplitEvent(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    private void DeleteHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Button)sender; // fyi

        if (DeleteEvent != null)
        {
            DeleteEvent(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kory, thanks for your time and answer. Actually it's far beyond expectations. I was hoping for some hints or components name that I should look up but I got some solid base for my experiments. Great proof of concept and this debug stuff (borders, background colours, etc) are really neat. Thanks again, really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `ÌtemTemplateSelector` to assign different templates based on a variable.

In your code behind we have a simple `Rows` property. This will be used to show how many rows are displayed in the Grid.

MainWindow.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public int[] Rows{ get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        this.Rows= new int[] { 1, 2, 1, 3 };
    }
}
```

The ItemTemplateSelector.cs which chooses the correct `DataTemplate` based on `Rows`

```
public class RowTemplateSelecter: DataTemplateSelector
{        
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;
        int rows = 1;
        int.TryParse(item.ToString(), out rows);
        switch (rows)
        {
            case 1:
                return element.FindResource("OneRow") as DataTemplate;
            case 2:
                return element.FindResource("TwoRows") as DataTemplate;
            case 3:
                return element.FindResource("ThreeRows") as DataTemplate;
            default:
                return element.FindResource("OneRow") as DataTemplate;

        }          
    }
}
```

Finally MainWindow.xaml where we add our 3 templates and the ItemTemplateSelector

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="OneRow">
        <Grid Background="Red" Width="100" Height="100">

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TwoRows" >
        <Grid Width="100" Height="100">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Fill="Blue"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="Green" Grid.Row="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ThreeRows">
        <Grid Width="100" Height="100">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Fill="Yellow"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="Orange" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="Black" Grid.Row="2"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:RowTemplateSelecter x:Key="RowSelector"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="rectangles"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}"
                  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource RowSelector}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer SWilko. It's a very nice example and it's doing exactly what I was asking for. My only worry is that if I'd like to introduce more "templates" (like vertical splits, different ratios etc) my MainWindow.xaml would grow very big. There's probably a way to move it out somehow but that's probably a question for other time.
Apologies that I’m gonna accept the other one (because it’s bit more flexible), but thanks again, really appreciate the answer.